# How to prevent the compiler from checking the syntactic correctness of a certain branch

Tags: c++, templates, ostream, if-constexpr

I basically want to select one of the branches at compile-time but can't figure out how to address the error that shows up.

Here is the code [(link)](https://godbolt.org/z/779bhEE6s):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename charT>
struct Foo
{
    using value_type = charT;

    std::vector<value_type> vec;

    void printVec( std::basic_ostream<charT>& out_stream )
    {
        out_stream.write( std::data( vec ), std::size( vec ) ).write( "\n", 1 );
    }
};

// specialization for char
template <>
void Foo<char>::printVec( std::basic_ostream<char>& out_stream )
{
    out_stream.write( std::data( vec ), std::size( vec ) ).write( "\n", 1 );
}

// specialization for wchar_t
template <>
void Foo<wchar_t>::printVec( std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>& out_stream )
{
    out_stream.write( std::data( vec ), std::size( vec ) ).write( L"\n", 1 );
}

int main( )
{
    using FooChar = Foo<char>;
    using FooWideChar = Foo<wchar_t>;

#define IS_CHAR 1

#if IS_CHAR == 1
    FooChar foo;
    foo.vec.resize( 10, '$' );
#else
    FooWideChar foo;
    foo.vec.resize( 10, L'#' );
#endif

    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< decltype( foo )::value_type,
                                   decltype( std::cout )::char_type > )
    {
        foo.printVec( std::cout );
    }
    else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v< decltype( foo )::value_type,
                                        decltype( std::wcout )::char_type > )
    {
        foo.printVec( std::wcout ); // this is where the compile error occurs
    }
    else
    {
        static_assert( std::is_same_v< decltype( foo )::value_type,
                                       decltype( std::cout )::char_type > ||
                       std::is_same_v< decltype( foo )::value_type,
                                       decltype( std::wcout )::char_type >,
                       "character type not supported" );
    }
}
```

The error message:

```bash
cannot convert 'std::wostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>'} to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&'
```

The message is self-explanatory however I still don't know how to get around this issue. I guess this problem would not arise if the compiler wouldn't check the syntax of the statement inside the `else if` branch. Is there any way to make the above snippet compile?

Comment: If constexpr only works the way you want in templates, so you need to extract this code to a function template.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. So move all the if constexpr to those two print functions? Or use std::enable_if? I still am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lift your `if constexpr` logic into a template function:

```
template <typename charT>
void printIt( Foo<charT>& foo )
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<charT, char> )
        foo.printVec( std::cout );
    else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<charT, wchar_t> )
        foo.printVec( std::wcout );
    else
        static_assert( sizeof(charT) == 0, "character type not supported" );
}
```

Also, note you don't need two definitions of `printVec()` for `char`.  You can simply declare it in the class without a definition:

```
void printVec( std::basic_ostream<charT>& out_stream );
```

It should probably be `const`, then `printIt()` can take `const Foo&`.

Comment: So does this add to the runtime cost? Also, can we just put this logic into the `printVec` which is defined inside the class `Foo`?

Comment: No it does not add to the runtime cost.  Yes you can put `std::cout` and `std::wcout` directly into `printVec()`, but I assumed you wanted to be able to pass other streams than the standard streams (such as a file) to `printVec()`.  If not, there's no reason for `printIt()` to be separate.

Comment: Yes, I want that flexibility. Thanks for the info.